Need to Fetch the data in PDO::FETCH_CLASS in PHP
I am facing a little problem,
I have a User class that connects to the database using a static::method and fetching all users using my custom method find_all(), the result is gonna be returned associative array or objects, I need the data to be objects associated to my class, so I have to use fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Users'), the problem is, i want to use my class which it is using a __construct() method to build objects, it gives me properties are required, I shouldn't use default values in this case, cuze I want the result from the database instead, I hope you got that, thanks in advance.
I tried to use default values, buy aren't working with this situation

Try this
PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE
This will allows the properties to be set before the constructor is called, enabling you to initialize your object properly without running into issues with missing required properties.

public function __construct($name = null, $email = null, $phone = null, $country = null, $password = null) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->email = $email;
    $this->phone = $phone;
    $this->country = $country;
    $this->password = $password;
}

public static function find_all() {
    $stmt = static::connect_database()->query('SELECT * FROM users');
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'User');
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}

Works fine, thanks to @M.hammad_Nazir & @Muhammad_Arsal

If another answer helped you solve your problem, then you will need to edit that other answer with further details once you have sufficient privilege to do so.

As you can see, I am new in stackoverflow, Can you tell more, how can I do that

Sure. Just below your question there are some tags for the question and below those tags there is an Edit button that you can click on.
